# How to pin statusbar and bottombar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter so please don't kill me if my question is not clear. I want to make a status bar and bottom bar seen all the time. Now by default they are hidden when I tab on the screen they appeared.

How can I make them seen or visible all the time ?

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'HomePage.dart';
class business extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _business createState() => new _business();
}
class _business extends State<business> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  @override
  void initState(){
    controller = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
   // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: new Icon(
          Icons.business,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: new Text(
          "مرسال بيزنيس",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        bottom: new TabBar(controller: controller,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,color: Colors.white),text: "مرسال ستور",),
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.school,color: Colors.white),text: "مرسال أكاديمي"),
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance,color:    Colors.white),text: "مساحات مرسال"),
          ],),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF009091),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(

        // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140,left: 25,right: 25),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:
      new BottomNavigationBar(items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الرئيسية",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.business, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "مرسال بيزنيس",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.local_activity, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "أنشطة مرسال",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "تبرع",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.help, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الأسئلة الشائعة",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            ))
      ],
      onTap: onTabTapped,),
    );
  }
  void onTabTapped(void index)
  {
  }
}
```

Now the result is like [image]
with no status bar or bottom bar

but i want it to be like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all import

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Then call this

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)
```

line before `MaterialApp` call in `MyApp()` like below to prevent it from hiding:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: business (),
    );
  }
}

class business extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _business createState() => new _business();
}
class _business extends State<business> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  @override
  void initState(){
    controller = new TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: new Icon(
          Icons.business,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: new Text(
          "مرسال بيزنيس",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        bottom: new TabBar(controller: controller,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,color: Colors.white),text: "مرسال ستور",),
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.school,color: Colors.white),text: "مرسال أكاديمي"),
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance,color:    Colors.white),text: "مساحات مرسال"),
          ],),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF009091),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 140,left: 25,right: 25),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:
      new BottomNavigationBar(items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الرئيسية",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.business, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "مرسال بيزنيس",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.local_activity, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "أنشطة مرسال",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "تبرع",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.help, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الأسئلة الشائعة",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            ))
      ],
        onTap: onTabTapped,),
    );
  }
  void onTabTapped(void index)
  {
  }
}
```